# Tomcat not finding existing classes

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have two virtual machines with seemingly identical configuration (created from the same VM template, and diff'ing the Tomcat folder yielded no difference apart from host name configurations). On both machines, the same web applications are deployed.

One machine works fine. On the other machine, I get errors because classes are not found. I restarted tomcat 3 times, and always get a different error, also in different applications. One such error is this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes
    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener.requestInitialized(RequestContextListener.java:64)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

In every occurence of this error so far, the missing class (e.g. `ServletRequestAttributes`) resides in the same jar as the class that needs it (e.g. `RequestContextListener`).

I am using CentOS, Apache 2.2.3, Tomcat 6.0.30 and Oracle JDK 1.6.0_24 on both machines. Tomcat is configured with plenty heap and perm gen space (also identical on both machines).

---

It seems that [Tomcat 6 "losing" classes in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190939/tomcat-6-losing-classes-in-production) is a similar problem, but without solution so far.

One possible problem named there is "you may have reached the max number of open file handles in the OS". With rudimentary Linux knowledge, I managed to execute some commands found on the internet, which tell me that

- max file handles is 6815744 on both machines (`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`),
- current usage is 10710 on the failing and 10200 on the correct machine (`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`),
- max file handles per process is 1024 (`ulimit -n`),
- current usage by Tomcat is 641 on the failing and 686 on the correct machine (`lsof -p <TOMCAT-PID> | wc -l`).

---

UPDATE: I restarted the failing Tomcat, and opened all applications at once in a browser. The file usage of Tomcat went up to 1926. Now I see a NoClassDefFoundError in almost every application, and I also see this message in one log file:

```
2011-12-12 18:38:36,225 ERROR [TP-Processor3] [rplansecurity] org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:397) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
```

I did the same on the correct Tomcat, and it failed, too. So it seems there is no difference in the two machines here: Both seem to open too many files.

Comment: Which JDK exactly are you using? Oracle or OpenJDK or GCJ? GCJ is very buggy.

Comment: are you sure this jar is in the JVM classpath when starting up tomcat? Try "ps -ef |  grep 'tomcat'" or even connect with visualVM/jconsole to see the classpath. It's good you have an identical app working. All you have to do is compare the two classpaths

Comment: @BalusC I am using the Oracle JDK.

Comment: @dimitrisli I checked that the webapp folders are identical. Also, the missing class is in the same jar file as a class that is found. And that jar file is not provided by Tomcat itself, but only by the applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Max number of open files exceeded would be my first thought. I also think that 'ulimit -n' shows max file handles per user and not per process, but I might be wrong. Keep in mind that Tomcat might run under different user as well.

I would try to start tomcat with '-verbose:class' to see which classes and from where are being loaded to try to see if there are any sort of pattern there.

Comment: By switching to the Tomcat user, I see that `ulimit -n` shows the same result: 1024. When starting Tomcat with the `-verbose:class` option, I see tons of classes being loaded, but no failure messages.

Comment: Increasing the file limit, with `ulimit -n 4096`, seems to help. I restarted Tomcat and opened all applications at once in a browser, without one missing a class. The output of `lsof -p <TOMCAT-PID>|wc -l` goes up to 3305, and then falls to 650.

Comment: Cool, so my analysis was right then. You can probably add call to ulimit to catalina.sh script

Comment: This is also a good answer for "how to run my Tomcat in verbose mode". I was searching for help for this topic and could not find any thread that answers it, except this one :-)

Comment: @maximdim can we write the loaded class to a fiele . now it is comming up in tomcat catalina.out?